# The closure in a subspace.

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ a subspace I have the following question.

If $A\subseteq Y$ do we have
$$cl_Y(A)=cl_X(A)\cap Y,$$
where $cl_Y$ denotes the closure in the space $Y$?

**Try:** We have that $cl_X(A)\cap Y$ is a closed subset of $Y$ containing $A$, so this gives $cl_Y(A)\subseteq cl_X(A)\cap Y$. What about the other direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/268943/210479

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be a closed subset containing $A$, $F= F'\cap X$ where $F'$ is a closed subset of $X$. $F'$  contains $cl_X(A)$. Thus $F'\cap Y= F$ contains $cl_X(A)\cap Y$ which thus the smallest closed subset of $Y$ containing $A$ by definition, it is the adherence of $A$ in $Y$.

Comment: Don't you mean $F=F'\cap Y$?