# For dominant morphism locally of finite type, why the dimension of generic fiber is same as the transcendence degree of function fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book, p.466, statement of Lemma 14.106 and and some question arises :

> Lemma 14.106. (1) Let $X$, $Y$ be irreducible locally noetherian schemes, let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism locally of finite type, and denote by $\xi$ and $\eta$, resp., the generic points of $X$ and $Y$. Let $e:=\dim f^{-1}(\eta)=\operatorname{trdeg}_{\kappa(\eta)}\kappa(\xi)$ be the dimension of the generic fiber. Let $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$. Then
> $$  e+ \dim\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \ge \operatorname{trdeg}_{\kappa(y)}\kappa(x) +\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \tag{14.26.1}$$

**Q.** Why can we write $\dim f^{-1}(\eta)=\operatorname{trdeg}_{\kappa(\eta)}\kappa(\xi)$ ?

Perhaps, can we try to use next theorem ( Gortz's book, p.126, Theorem 5.22- (1) ) :

[image]

?

In applying the Theorem 5.22-(1), I think that there are several technical diffiulties

**Q.1** If we use the theorem 5.22 'directly', then the generic fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible? I found an assoicated theorems ( Gortz's book, Exercise 6.15. )

> Exercise 6.15. Let $Y$ be an integral scheme with generic point $\eta$ and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism. Let $X$ be reduced ( resp. irreducible, resp. normal, resp. regular ). Show that the generic fiber $X_{\eta}$ has the same property.

Can we try to use this exercise? A technical subtlety is that in our situation ( Lemma 14.106 ) , $Y$ may not be intergral scheme. By introducing its underlying reduced subscheme $Y_{\operatorname{red}}$ of a scheme $Y$, we can deduce that $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible ?

**Q.2** In the above lemma 14.106, since $f$ is dominant, $\xi \in f^{-1}(\eta)$. Then

Q. 2-1) $\xi$ is generic point of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ ( if $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible )? I think that this is true as [Closure of a subset of a subspace of a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268943/closure-of-a-subset-of-a-subspace-of-a-topological-space).

Q. 2-2) If Q. 2-1) is true, then **the residue field of $\xi$ 'in $f^{-1}(\eta)$' is same as the residue field $\kappa(\xi)$ 'in $X$'** ?

If these questions Q.1, Q.2 are true, then we may apply the Theorem 5.22 and get our disired result.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In Theorem 5.22 we have the transcendence degree over $k$, while in Lemma 14.106 there is transcendence degree over $k(\eta)$. So this is not such a direct application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every adjective here is preserved by passing to an open subscheme, we can assume that $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} B$ (also, since the inclusion $\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\eta)\to Y$ factors through any non-empty open immersion, the fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is not changed). $f$ is now necessarily finite type because it's affine. We can also assume that $A$ and $B$ are integral domains since reduction preserves the underlying topological space of the fibers and the residue field at the generic point. The fact that $f$ is dominant then implies that $B$ is a subring of $A$. Then $f^{-1}(\eta)=\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_B K(B))$ is the spectrum of a localization of $A$ (which is an integral domain) and thus irreducible. The residue field at the generic point of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is $K(A\otimes_B K(B))=K(A)=\kappa(\xi)$. $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is now an irreducible finite type scheme over $K(B)=\kappa(\eta)$ and thus $\dim f^{-1}(\eta)=\operatorname{trdeg}_{\kappa(\eta)} \kappa(\xi)$.

Comment: O.K. Thank you.  1. I think that we can show the irreduciblity of $f^{-1}(\eta)$ by other route : Since $f$ is dominant, $\xi \in f^{-1}(\eta)$. Then $\bar{\{ \xi\}}^{f^{-1}(\eta)} = \bar{\{\eta\}}^{X} \cap f^{-1}(\eta) = X \cap f^{-1}(\eta) =f^{-1}(\eta)$, which shows that $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreduicble ( topological closure of singleton is irreducible ). True argument?   2. Anyway, why $K(A \otimes_B K(B))=K(A)$?   3. Possible errata :  In the Theorem 5.22 in my above question, the property 'locally of finite type' is sufficient ; googling 'errata Gortz', go into p.126

Comment: P.s. In fact, I think that I solved the problem before, by other(?) method ( using the Gortz's book Proposition 4.20 ) ; i.e., I think that I prove the question Q. 2-2) in my question. Anyway thanks for giving other argument, posiibly making detour the Proposition 4.20.

Comment: Can you explain why $K(A\otimes_B K(B)) =K (A)$? I am still don't understand why this is true.

Comment: $A\otimes_B K(B)$ is the localization of $A$ at $B\setminus\{0\}$ and so sits naturally in $K(A)$. Since it contains $A$, its fraction field is also $K(A)$.

Comment: O.K. Thank you :)~